# Horizontal Custom ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, material-design

I want my custom build ListBox to display the items on the next line if their size exceeds the available width of their parent control.

Following is my XAML for this purpose.

```
<materialDesign:Card>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="DemiBold" FontSize="30">Schedule</TextBlock>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Schedule, Source={StaticResource dc}}">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ListBoxItem>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock>Day:</TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <materialDesign:TimePicker materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Time In" SelectedTime="{Binding Value.TimeIn}" />

                                    <materialDesign:TimePicker materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Time Out" SelectedTime="{Binding Value.TimeOut}"  />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ListBoxItem>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:Card>
```

Following is the Output for the above XAML

[image: Output of the Above writte]

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `WrapPanel` instead of a `StackPanel`, then.

Answer (score 0):

As **H.B.** said, the **ItemPanel** control you should use is a **WrapPanel** that let you achieve what you want (when there isn't enough space for your control, it creates a new line).

Here it is an example:

```
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```